# Is there anyway to provide a clickable link on a HTML page to save a contact to a mobile phone?

Tags: mobile, mobile-website, web

I'm looking to allow my users to my mobile web click on a link to straight away add my contact into their phone (iphone/android).

I know there's a tel scheme available and I'm currently using that on top. Is there anyway to provide First Name, Last Name, Email, Phone in a combined solution to store into my user's phone?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Contacts API](http://www.w3.org/TR/contacts-api/) spec in conjunction with Permissions for Device API Access (you need to have permission to write or read contacts), but no browser supports it yet.

Mozilla Labs is working on it, but it is only in the desktop.

As for schemas there is http://schema.org/Person but this is only used by search engines, for now, maybe in the near future browsers "learn" to use these schemas.

There is also the hybrid web/native app solution with PhoneGap, but it is not a mobile web solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create your contact in .vcf. If user click the link to your vcf, your contact will be downloaded an then opened for confirmation to save into phone book